# Entity Framework 4 - Insert a many-to-many

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm new to EF4 and I'm trying to insert a record from a many-to-many relationship. I got 3 tables:

- A(ID,Description)
- B(ID,Code)
- AB(aID,bID) <--A and B relation

The problem is that when I call SaveChanges(), it throws an exception and it's trying to insert a new record into B. I don't want that, it supposed to just add the link. Here is my code:

```
var a = new A(){Description="Example"};

var b = context.B.Single(B => B.ID == paramID);

a.B.Add(b);

context.A.AddObject(a);

context.SaveChanges() <---- here it throws the exception
```

From my research, the code above should and a new record to A and create a link between A and B and store it in the AB table, right?

I'm missing something?

EDIT:

This is the exception that I'm getting:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MIC', table 'dbo.B'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

If you note, I'm just trying to add the many-to-many link not to create a new record in table B. I even tried to leave a.B empty and it still throws the exception described above.

Comment: The exception type and message seems relevant to this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try attaching `A` to the context before adding `B` to the collection:

```
var a = new A { Description = "Example" };
var b = context.B.Single(B => B.ID == paramID);

context.A.AddObject(a);
a.B.Add(b);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunately I don't have a chance to test this now, but my guess is that when adding `A` to the context, EF sets the state of the objects in the `B` collection to `Added` too. In that case this should solve the problem.

Alternatively you could try going the other way round - adding `A` to the list of `B`:

```
var a = new A { Description = "Example" };
var b = context.B.Single(B => B.ID == paramID);

b.A.Add(a);

context.SaveChanges();
```

This does seem like a cleaner approach in your case.

Comment: You might want to check if the record in the link table already exists before attempting to add...(i.e. change Single to SingleOrDefault and then only add if b is null ...)